# PANIC: Could not open: ¨8W

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, panic

First of all just let me say that I have looked through the solutions on stackoverflow and have not found one that has worked. These include:

- linking folders (but that was absurd for my case)
- Creating the environment (system) variables for the computer and eclipse.

Still when I run Android Virtual Device Manager on eclipse and when I start the AVD I get:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_4_65in_720p_Galaxy_Nexus'
>
> PANIC: Could not open: ¨8W

I have tried other devices still it doesn't work. I have two hard drives but the AVDM says the correct path up top which is D:\Users\User.android\avd

Anyone got a solution?

Thanks a lot.

P.S.: It says the AVDs are "A valid Android Virtual Device."

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a new user environment variable (Windows 7):

Start Menu > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings (on the left) > Environment Variables

Add a new user variable (at the top) that points your home user directory:
Variable name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME
Variable value: C:\Users>User Name<

Also,  move the .android folder in your Users directory to the same directory your SDK is in

Answer (score 0):

maybe something went wrong with your configurations  .

close eclipse and adt , and then delete the ".android" folders from both the drive you have installed it into , and from your user folder.

also , try to uninstall the sdk tools from the sdk manager , and then re-install them . in addition , try to use a little older android version for the emulator .

another solution is to set the environment parameter of your system:

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME = C:\users\my.username
```

if nothing helps , try to completely uninstall anything related to android , and install on a different drive (or the default one).

anyway , this issue was already reported and handled by some users [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084) .

Answer (score 0):

Try to run eclipse "As Administrator".
Of course after adding the path and user home.

It works every time for me. When i simple "run" eclipse it gives me

```
PANIC: Could not open: ¨8W //or something similar, almost different each time
```

When i "run as administrator" it works perfect every time.